# exponential differential integral equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, integral-equations

I have a following equation, which has a singular kernel,

```
0.282095` Integrate[
    Derivative[1][A11][k]/Sqrt[-k + t] , {k, 0, 
     t}] + ((-1 + E^A11[t]) Derivative[1][A11][t])/(Sqrt[
      2] Sqrt[-1 + E^A11[t] - A11[t]]) == 
 0.5` (0.2` - 0.0433792711308264` Sqrt[-1 + E^A11[t] - A11[t]] + 
    A11[t] - 
    0.015336865356479351` Integrate[(2 Sqrt[
          1/(-k + t)] Derivative[1][A11][k])/Sqrt[π] , {k, 0, t}])
```

and the Initial condition is `A11[0]==0`

I used following series expansion for the nonlinear parts

```
Series[Sqrt[-1 + E^A11[t] - A11[t]], {A11[t], 0, 3}]
Series[(-1 + E^A11[t]), {A11[t], 0, 3}]
```

The above expressions are replaced in the equation, Then I used Laplace transform to solve the equation, where the answer is

```
A11[s_] = 0.1`/(
 s (-0.48466313872191963` + 0.5153368612780803` Sqrt[s] + s))
```

Finally, the Laplace inverse package was used to  obtain the solution 
[image]

The solution is not so bad, but I am wondering is it possible to solve these kind of questions in original form without any assumptions. I do not know how to write this equation in the standard Volterra integral equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nonlinear integral-differential equation in the question can be solved iteratively as follows.  Begin with the expression in the question, but with `2/Sqrt[π]` factored out of the second integral (because `Simplify` does not automatically remove constants from integrands).

```
eq1 = Simplify[0.282095` Integrate[Derivative[1][A11][k]/Sqrt[-k + t], {k, 0, t}] + 
    ((-1 + E^A11[t]) Derivative[1][A11][t])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[-1 + E^A11[t] - A11[t]]) == 
    0.5` (0.2` - 0.0433792711308264` Sqrt[-1 + E^A11[t] - A11[t]] + A11[t] - 
    0.015336865356479351` Integrate[Sqrt[1/(-k + t)] Derivative[1][A11][k], {k, 0, t}] 
    2/Sqrt[π]), 0 < k < t];
```

and solve it for `A11'[t]`.

```
ap = Simplify[A11'[t] /. First@Solve[eq1, A11'[t]]
(* (0.03067377677953718 - 0.03067377677953718*E^A11[t] + 
   0.1414213562373095*Sqrt[-1. + E^A11[t] - 1.*A11[t]] + 
   (0.03067377677953718 + 0.7071067811865475*Sqrt[-1. + E^A11[t] - 
   1.*A11[t]])*A11[t] - 0.4111796229566854*Sqrt[-1. + E^A11[t] - 
   1.*A11[t]]*Integrate[A11'[k]/Sqrt[-k + t], {k, 0, t}])/(-1. + 1.*E^A11[t]) *)
```

The question further specifies that `A11[0] == 0`.  Inserting this into `ap` yields

```
(Series[ap, {A11[t], 0, 0}, Assumptions -> A11[t] >= 0] /. t -> 0) // Normal
(* 0.1 *)
```

In other words, the corresponding value of `A11'[0]` is `0.1`.  Now, `NDSolve` could solve `A11'[t] == ap` without difficulty, were it not for the Abel integral, `Integrate[A11'[k]/Sqrt[-k + t], {k, 0, t}]`.  So, let us approximate `A11'[k]` in the integral by `A11'[0]`, use `NDSolve` to obtain a better approximation for `A11'[k]`, and continue iterating until `A11[k]` converges.  Define

```
int[n_, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[sp[n - 1][k]/Sqrt[t - k], {k, 0, t}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
apn[n_] = ap /. Integrate[A11'[k]/Sqrt[t - k], {k, 0, t}] -> int[n, t];
```

and iterate

```
tmin = 1/1000; sp[-1][t_] = .1;
Do[{s[n], sp[n]} = Quiet@NDSolveValue[{A11'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{apn[n], t > tmin}}, 1/10], A11[0] == 0}, {A11, A11'}, {t, 0, 1}], {n, 0, 5}]
```

Fortunately, this process actually converges, and rapidly.

```
Join[{.1}, Table[s[n][1], {n, 0, 5}]]
(* {0.1, 0.0799404, 0.0885934, 0.0854804, 0.0864669, 0.0861837, 0.0862587} *)

Plot[{0.1 t, s[0][t], s[5][t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Shown are the initial guess (blue), the result of the first iteration (tan), and the result of the sixth iteration (green).  The entire computation takes only seconds.

Comment: Thank you, it is very interesting, but A11[0] == 0, not A11[0] == 1. The solution is correct. I think it is just a typo.

Comment: @hesamaero  Yes, a typo, now corrected.  Thanks for pointing it out, as well as for accepting the answer.  By the way, your equation can be recast as a Volterra equation of the second kind coupled to a first order ODE.  However, it is not clear to me that doing so would be helpful.